# Convert c# list of objects to JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

How to parse c# object to JSON?

This is the code i got:

Model:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class HolidayModel
    {
        public int HolidayID { get; set; }
        public string HolidayDescription { get; set; }
        public string HolidayStartDate { get; set; }
        public string HolidayEndDate { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public string HolidayOld { get; set; }
        public string HolidayNew { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public int HolidaySelectedYear { get; set; }

        public int StartDay { get; set; }
        public int StartMonth { get; set; }
        public int StartYear { get; set; }

        public int EndDay { get; set; }
        public int EndMonth { get; set; }
        public int EndYear { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetEvents()
{
    List<Holiday> holidays = conn.Holidays.ToList();

    ViewBag.holidaysJson = Json(holidays, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return View();
}
```

and in View i try to print the json in an alert box with the following code:

```
<script>
    alert("@ViewBag.holidaysJson");
</script>
```

but i get the empty alert box.

What's the problem here?

Comment: holidaysResult != holidaysJson

Comment: I just changed it but i still get an empty alert box

Comment: Doesn't calling `Json` simply return a [`JsonResult` instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult)? Is this really what you want?

Comment: Little tip: Use console.log instead of alerts, so you can navigate inside the result you get

Answer (score 3):

You can just simply pass the model back to view and then convert it to JSON using `Json.Encode` method:

Controller code would be :

```
public ActionResult GetEvents()
{
    List<Holiday> holidays = conn.Holidays.ToList(); 
    return View(holidays); 
}
```

and in view:

```
@model List<Holiday>
<script>
    var holidaysJson = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); // json object
    alert(JSON.stringify(holidaysJson)); // converting it to string representation
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonconvert.serializeobject` method.

```
public ActionResult GetEvents()
{
    List<Holiday> holidays = conn.Holidays.ToList();
    ViewBag.holidaysResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(holidays);
    return View(holidays);
}
```